# How to order the rows information of a data set

Tags: r, rows

please help me... I have a data set containing information about academic degrees per year, like this:

```
Year1  Deg_Year1  Year2  Deg_Year2  Year3  Deg_Year3  Year4  Deg_Year4  Year5  Deg_Year5   
2001   College    2004   Master      NA      NA        NA       NA        NA       NA
2004   College    2004   Master      2010    PHD       NA       NA        NA       NA 
2006   Master     2006   College     NA      NA        NA       NA        NA       NA
2016   Master     NA     NA          NA      NA        NA       NA        NA       NA
2002   Master     2003   Master      2004    College   2004     Master    NA       NA  
2002   Master     2002   College     NA      NA        NA       NA        NA       NA
```

I want to obtain a data frame that contains the year and the highest academic degree obtained before 2015, like this:

```
YearX   Highest_Degree
2004    Master
2010    PHD
2006    Master
NA      NA
2004    Master
2002    Master
```

Can someone please help me?
Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a `vector` of degrees in an order and then `match` against the 'Deg_Year' columns, get the maximum value in each row with `max.col` to subset the values and the corresponding 'Year' in each row

```
v1 <- c('Master', 'PHD')
nm1 <- grep('Deg', names(df1))
m1 <- sapply(df1[nm1], match, table = v1, nomatch = 0)
i1 <- max.col(m1) * NA^(!rowSums(m1!=0))
YearX <- df1[nm1-1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)), i1)]
Highest_Degree <- df1[nm1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)), i1)]
data.frame(YearX, Highest_Degree)
#  YearX Highest_Degree
#1  2004         Master
#2  2010            PHD
#3  2006         Master
#4    NA           <NA>
#5  2004         Master
#6  2002         Master
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(Year1 = c(2001L, 2004L, 2006L, 2016L, 2002L, 2002L
), Deg_Year1 = c("College", "College", "Master", "College", "Master", 
"Master"), Year2 = c(2004L, 2004L, 2006L, NA, 2003L, 2002L), 
    Deg_Year2 = c("Master", "Master", "College", NA, "Master", 
    "College"), Year3 = c(NA, 2010L, NA, NA, 2004L, NA), Deg_Year3 = c(NA, 
    "PHD", NA, NA, "College", NA), Year4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    2004L, NA), Deg_Year4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "Master", NA), 
    Year5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Deg_Year5 = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Year1", "Deg_Year1", "Year2", 
"Deg_Year2", "Year3", "Deg_Year3", "Year4", "Deg_Year4", "Year5", 
"Deg_Year5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much friend... only I have a question : what is "i1"? I am new in R. Thank you again!

Comment: @DavidVivas Sorry, I forgot to put that here.  Corrected

Comment: I have an error : "Unsupported use of matrix or array for column indexing" in line 5:  YearX ... why ?   Thank you !

Comment: @DavidVivas  Could you please check your dataset column classes.  I assumed it as `character`.  I have updated my post with the data I used.  It is working fine

Comment: Sorry Dear @akrun. I have another question, please help me again! Thank you!!!   I have modified observation number 4, the change is "Master" instead of "College" in column "Deg_Year1" and this change is like a new problem for me because whit this change I have another result in line #4: 2016 Master. How can I limit to only years before 2015?? Thank you again !!

Comment: @DavidVivas  Could you please post as a new question as it is not clear to me about the logic for other cases

Comment: Thank you so much!!  I have posted a new question with title: "How to order the rows information of a data set with two criteria" . I hope you can help me. Thank you again !!